# Powershell 3.0: Unable to send e-mail to myself using send-mailmessage cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've been trying to debug this for a couple of days now and I'm at my wits end. Here's the code:

```
$gmailPwd = 'password'
$gmailUser = 'my.email@gmail.com'
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($gmailUser,$gmailPwd)
$param = @{
SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
Port = 587
UseSsl = $true
Credential = $cred
From = $gmailUser
To = $gmailUser
Subject = 'Test'
Body = "Test"
}
Send-MailMessage @param
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
New-Object : Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "Password1234", for "PSCredential" to type "System.Security.SecureString": "Cannot convert the "Password1234" value of type "System.String" to type 
"System.Security.SecureString"."
At line:4 char:9
+ $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($gmailUser,$gmailP ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
At line:15 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage @param
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

I'm just not really sure what the error message is getting at. And, for the record, no Password1234 is not really the password, but it is analogous to the real thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `[PSCredential]`'s constructor doesn't accept plain text passwords. It has to be a secure string.

From [How to create a PSCredential object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/koteshb/archive/2010/02/13/powershell-creating-a-pscredential-object.aspx):

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "PlainTextPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
```

Comment: Ok, cool. So that fixed the password issue, but now I'm still dealing with the second error. Send-MailMessage : `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
At line:14 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage @param
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage`

Comment: @GalenH I don't see any problems with your existing code so I'm not sure why it's failing, except maybe that you have the email address or password wrong. Try removing any dots `.` from the email address when using them in the user name field. Dots are optional in a gmail address and maybe they are supposed to be left out when using it as a user name. Just speculation I haven't tested that.

Comment: I am confident in the e-mail address and password. After investigating the 5.5.1 error code it looks like it's an authentication issue on the server side. I've gone ahead and authorized script-access and have also authorized the computer I'm using, but that hasn't produced any meaningful results. I'm a bit stumped as well. Edit: I should say, I authorized it within the associated Google account.